# VBA Looping through Tables in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm using VBA to automatically create a column and update the column in several tables in my access DB. I have got the code working but I want to make it dynamic using a loop. When I make it into a loop the code gives me an error message. How would I make my code dynamic?
For example this code works, it adds a column (ID) to table (1234_CompanyA) and populates it with 1234-E.

```
Dim strDdl As String
strDdl = "ALTER TABLE 1234_CompanyA ADD COLUMN ID TEXT(255)"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl

Dim strDdl2 As String
strDdl2 = "UPDATE [1234_CompanyA] SET [1234_CompanyA].[ID]=""1234-E"""
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl2
```

However I want to make the code into a loop by defining the table as an object using the code:

```
Dim tbl(3) As Object
Dim strDdl As String
Dim strDdl2 As String
Dim id(3) as String

tbl(1) = [1234_CompanyA]
tbl(2) = [1234_CompanyB]
tbl(3) = [1234_CompanyC]

id(1)= "1234-E"
id(2)= "5678-C"
id(3)= "9012-G"

For i = 1 To 3

    strDdl = "ALTER TABLE tbl(i) COLUMN ID TEXT(255)"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl

    strDdl2 = "UPDATE tbl(i) SET tbl(i).[ID]= id(1)"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl2

Next i
```

How would I get the code working as a loop?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you're adding fields to your tables at run-time then that's a big indicator that your database design is flawed..

Comment: `Dim id(3) As String` will more than likely create four elements in the array - `id(0)` to `id(3)`.  You could add `Option Base 1` at the top of your module, or use `Dim id(1 To 3) As String`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I'm a beginner so all tips are useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your commands like this:

```
Dim tbl(3) As Object
Dim strDdl As String
Dim strDdl2 As String
Dim id(3) As String

tbl(1) = "[1234_CompanyA]"
tbl(2) = "[1234_CompanyB]"
tbl(3) = "[1234_CompanyC]"

id(1) = "1234-E"
id(2) = "5678-C"
id(3) = "9012-G"

For i = 1 To 3

    strDdl = "ALTER TABLE " & tbl(i) & " COLUMN ID TEXT(255)"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl

    strDdl2 = "UPDATE " & tbl(i) & " SET " & tbl(i) & ".[ID] = '" & id(1) & "'"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl2

Next i
```

Notice that the variables have been broken out and not embedded into the string, and that quotes were added to the `tbl` variables.